# Tell if a file is a directory on an FTP server

Tags: c++, c, ftp, libcurl, ftp-server

I am writing a c++ program that interfaces with an Apache FtpServer using libcurl. I was originally using the `LIST` command to get the contents of a directory but it was giving me a lot of information I didn't but had to parse any ways which lead to a lot unneeded overhead (especially when I was working with hundreds of thousands of files). In addition I needed a valid time stamp and it was giving me a shorthand that didn't include the year (so on January 1 all of the files on my computer looked outdated compared to the FTP server's). My solution was to use the `NLST` command to get only the names, then download the timestamps of each using `MDTM`. This worked awesome but then I ran into the major problem of not being able to tell if a file was a directory or not.

I am thinking the easiest way to do this is using the permissions to see if the first flag is set to `d`. FTP doesn't appear to have this functionality. Is there an easy way to tell if a filename is a directory or file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `CWD` command on the file to test if it is a directory or not. But failure may mean lack of permission, so you need to check the error code. For example:

```
ftp> cd atom.xml
550 Can't change directory to atom.xml: Not a directory
```

Alternatively, you can use the `NLST` command again on the file you want to test. If it is a plain file, you will just get the filename back. Otherwise, you will get a list of contents of the directory.

```
ftp> nlist atom.xml
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 53912
atom.xml
226 1 matches total

ftp> mkdir foo
257 "foo" : The directory was successfully created
ftp> nlist foo
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 53928
226 0 matches total
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for but it appears to be the only solution. Thanks man.